# Git only pull code from Master but not other branches

Tags: git

I am new to git and I am stucked here for a long time.
I have two branches, Master and Develop.  Develop has new code, Master has old code.
I am trying to set up another dev machine with the new code (Develop)
However, when I try to run the git commands, it keeps on pulling old code(master) , even when I switched to the new branch.

Sample Commands:

```
git clone waterver
git remote add origin watever
git checkout -b develop
git fetch origin develop
git pull origin develop
```

Try to go to the directory, and still see files of master and not develop.

Comment: `git remote add origin watever` isn't necessary, and probably won't even succeed. You'll have an `origin` already defined by `clone`.

Comment: Rather than "sample commands", how about showing "actual commands" and where their actual behavior differs from what you expect/want?

Answer (score 2):

This command

```
git checkout -b develop
```

creates a new local branch called `develop` that is based off of whatever commit or branch that you currently have checked out into your working copy, which, if you just cloned your repo, would probably be the `master` branch!

What you really want to do is tell `checkout` to create a new local branch based off of the remote-tracking branch `origin/develop`:

```
git clone <your repo>
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

#### Update

So as [@meager pointed out in the comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875641/git-only-pull-code-from-master-but-not-other-branches#comment34904623_22875716), an even shorter way to check out a local version of a remote branch is to simply leave out `-b`:

```
git clone <your repo>
git checkout <name of remote branch>
```

Comment: Just `git checkout develop` will be enough in any remotely modern version of Git. If you checkout a branch that doesn't exist locally but does exist remotely, Git will create a local branch and set it to track the remote branch, and then check it out.

Comment: Double check away, I use this every day, several times a day :p

Comment: @meagar O.M.G. you're right! :/ AHA, but here's the difference, the original poster used `-b`, which is why his original command didn't work! But you're right, taking out `-b` will work, and is shorter.